# Is there something in ES6 to collect iterator including the final return value?

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6

If I have a following generator:

```
function* generate() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    return 3;
}
```

Is there something built in in ES6 to get `[1, 2]` and `3` out of it (without doing `next` manually)?
If I only needed `1` and `2` I could use `for(of)`, but I want to get `3` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generators are not designed to work that way. If you want to get all the values at once, then I hardly see the point of using generators. If you must, you can do something like this -

```
function* generate() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    return 3;
}

var arr = [], k, it = generate();
do {
   k = it.next();
   arr.push(k.value);
} while (!k.done);

console.log(arr);
```